# Floating for longer text unexpected behaviour

Tags: css

Here's my whole very simple testing code (also added to [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L95GR/1/)):

```
<html>
<head></head>
<style>
    div {
        width: 100px;
        background: yellow;
    }
    ul {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        background: green;
    }
    li {
        clear: both;
    }
    span {
        float: left;
        margin-right: 10px;
        color: red;
    }
    span + span {
        color: blue;
    }

</style>
<body>
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>text <span>aaa</span> <span>bbb</span></li>
        <li>text2 text2 text2 text2 text2 <span>aaa</span> <span>bbb</span></li>
        <li>text <span>aaa</span> <span>bbb</span></li>
        <li>text <span>aaa</span> <span>bbb</span></li>
        <li>text <span>aaa</span> <span>bbb</span></li>
        <li>text <span>aaa</span> <span>bbb</span></li>
        <li>text <span>aaa</span> <span>bbb</span></li>
        <li>text <span>aaa</span> <span>bbb</span></li>
        <li>text <span>aaa</span> <span>bbb</span></li>

    </ul>
    test test

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem - in second li element there is more text and spans aren't floated in first line and are moved to the second line and to be honest I don't understand this behaviour. I would like them to behave the same as in other li elements and some part of text2 moved to the next lines when they simple reach container width

Question - how to fix it (the best option without wrapping text into any tag and without moving spans to the beginning of li element) and why browsers in this case do this the way I don't expect?

**EDIT - I've added screens what I want to achieve**

Current behaviour is:

[image: Current behaviour]

Desired behaviour is:

[image: Desired behaviour]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I found so far is using positioning instead of floats:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<style>
    div {
        width: 100px;
        background: yellow;
    }
    ul {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        background: green;
    }
    li {
        clear: both;
        position: relative;
        padding-left: 55px;

    }
    span {

        margin-right: 10px;
        color: red;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
    }

    span + span {
        color: blue;
        position: absolute;
        left: 25px;
    }

</style>
<body>
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>text <span>aaa</span> <span>bbb</span></li>
        <li> text2 text2 text2 text2 text2 <span>aaa</span> <span>bbb</span></li>
        <li>text <span>aaa</span> <span>bbb</span></li>
        <li>text <span>aaa</span> <span>bbb</span></li>
        <li>text <span>aaa</span> <span>bbb</span></li>
        <li>text <span>aaa</span> <span>bbb</span></li>
        <li>text <span>aaa</span> <span>bbb</span></li>
        <li>text <span>aaa</span> <span>bbb</span></li>
        <li>text <span>aaa</span> <span>bbb</span></li>

    </ul>
    test test
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

which gives following result:

[image: Achieved result]

It's not exactly I wanted but it's quite near. If anyone has other idea, please share

Answer (score 0):

That happens because you have a fixed width on your div.

If you increase the width of the div the text won't drop to the next line.

Also, because it is a float, when it is dropped to the next line it is floated left, but because there are items already there it gets placed at the end of the line instead of forming its own new line.

```
div {
        width: 150px;
        background: yellow;
    }
```

### Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/L95GR/3/

Comment: True, but unfortunately I need to have defined width of elements somewhere in CSS. How can it be solved when I need to have div width defined as in question?

Comment: Want to make sure I understand you... your width needs to be `100px`? so you are wondering how you can have it behave so the text doesn't drop to the line below? or so that it drops to its own new line?

Comment: I've added sample screenshots to question